# x64 code signing certificates?

Tags: windows-7, certificate, 64-bit, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

A couple of questions regarding x64 driver signing certificates:

1. Is it true that x64 driver signing certificates *must* be from Verisign?
2. Where can I buy a certificate cheaper than the $500 one published on the Verisign website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

False, VeriSign is not the only choice. Take a look at this list:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487315